# Fetching data from Google Trends API but recieving unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, postgresql, google-trends

I am trying to make use of the google trends api for a project and receiving some unexpected token error.

I am receiving the output entries but not overall output. **What should I do** in order to get data in correct tabular form.

```
try {

    var res = await googleTrends.interestByRegion({
        keyword: keyword,
        geo: "US-" + state
    }); //resolution:keyword

    res = JSON.parse(res);
    //var res = await sleep(2000);

    // for debugging.
    //console.log(res);
    if ("default" in res) {
        if ("geoMapData" in res["default"]) {
            for (var x in res["default"].geoMapData) {
                var row = res["default"].geoMapData[x];

                if ("geoName" in row && "value" in row) {
                    console.log(" - " + row.geoName + "\t\t" + row.value);
                    //console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>",x,row.value,row.geoName)

                    //insert statement

                    //var name1 = [name,row.geoName ,keyword]
                    // console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<<<---------",name1)
                    var name1 = [row.geoName]
                    var name2 = [keyword]
                    var name3 = row.value[0]

                    pool.query("INSERT INTO data(state,keyword,demand_value) VALUES($1,$2,$3)", [name1, name2, name3], (err, res) => {
                        console.log(err, res);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("Invalid row, missing fields.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
}
```

I am getting following errors

```js
Failed:SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0
House Cleaning/AZ
Failed:SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Sounds like the `interestByRegion` does not return JSON? The `JSON.parse` is the line that throws, right?

Comment: can you print the JSON that comes out of interestByRegion and show us the results?

Comment: maybe you can try-catch the parse and then just ignore the error?

Comment: maybe based on bad data input, perhaps try sanitizing the input by removing strange characters from the field "keyword" or "state" maybe.
maybe "state" is just empty, can you PRINT state and share the results??